# GSW and homomorphic addition on integers

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, ring-lwe

Is it possible to use the [GSW](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-40041-4_5) scheme (Gentry, Sahai, Waters) also on integer values and not just single bits? If not, are there any schemes that support integer arithmetic with the same nice property of not having to use an evaluation key?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a double account? See [Alex](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/86731/alex). you can [merge](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) them.

Comment: You are right, thank you